# Cannot send email with amazon ses through amazon lambda with python

Tags: python, email, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

i have a script in python that uses boto3 to send mail with amazon ses, on my pc it works fine.

but i ran it in amazon aws lambda but it does not connect to amazon ses.

I do not get any error in the cloud watch.

Plz Help. the boto3 just logs the

```
"Starting new HTTPS connection (1): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
"Starting new HTTPS connection (2): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
"Starting new HTTPS connection (3): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

What is the problem? why the boto3 does not connect o ses?

here are the rols of my lambda funtion

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
            "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }    
    ]
```

Now here is the code of boto3 sending the email

```
    response = boto3_client.send_email(Source=EMAIL_SENDER,
    Destination={'ToAddresses': desti, 'BccAddresses' :   ['micorreo@gmail.com'] 
        },
        Message={
        'Subject': {
            'Data': self.notificacion.get_asunto(),
            'Charset': 'UTF-8'
            },
        'Body': {
            'Html': {
                'Data': self._get_filled_template(),
                'Charset': 'UTF-8'
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Cloudwatch Logs

```
    [INFO]  2016-05-23T17:47:13.54Z Script start
    2016-05-23 17:47:13 UTC
    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
    2016-05-23 17:47:28 UTC
    [INFO]  2016-05-23T17:48:15.63Z Starting new HTTPS connection (2): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
    2016-05-23 17:48:15 UTC
    2016-05-23 17:49:15 UTC
    [INFO]  2016-05-23T17:49:15.651Z Starting new HTTPS connection (3): email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
    2016-05-23 17:49:15 UTC
    2016-05-23 17:49:57 UTC
    END RequestId: 583a67cd-210e-11e6-bd17-530da7dced22 
    2016-05-23 17:49:57 UTC
    2016-05-23 17:49:57 UTC
    REPORT RequestId: 583a67cd-210e-11e6-bd17-530da7dced22  Duration: 170003.43 ms  Billed Duration: 170000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB  Max Memory
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your lambda function isn't able to access the Internet at all?  If connected to a VPC, it needs to be on a private subnet with Internet access through a NAT instance or NAT gateway.

Comment: your lambda role needs the "ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail" to send email permissions.

Comment: @Shibashis i have checked my email permision and it looks good to me

`{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
            "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i have not consider that posibility, because SES is a amazon service la RDS, i can connect to rds. thats why i didnt consider that but i will check it out and i will tell you if that is the problem. btw it is a good point

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Your commend had the right answer, in effect. i didnt have a private subnet with a NAT gateway to let lambda access the internet connection